# Maven Setup - Not sure what to do with JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, maven, build, java-home

So I was following this tutorial to setup Maven: http://www.himainc.com/files/m2e.pdf

I got to page 4 and was told to "Add JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK"

I just assumed that my JAVA_HOME was setup fine, this is what it is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre`

But when I went to run my Maven project, I got this error: http://pastebin.com/RD9Y1DPY

Any ideas guys?

And, I would like to say, sometimes when I have asked questions on this site, people's responses have been along the lines of "if you cant figure this stuff out you shouldn't be attempting to ..... ". I am only 15 and I don't have any code support from anyone that I know IRL so I am sorry if my question is rather basic, and should be more of a prerequisite than anything.

//Josh

Answer (score 2):

You have to set JAVA_HOME to a *JDK* installation not to a *JRE*

```
SET JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
```